# Append/Prepend string to a large file in Scala

Tags: scala, file, append

I've got a large file that after some spark processing has a header inside it(but not at the top) so I have to append this string header to the first line of the file.

I tried to do this since I could not find any way to prepend directly to first line (first I read all large content, then I clear the entire file and finally overwrite the file with the header and then append all the large string)

```
val content: String = txtOutput.contentAsString
    txtOutput.clear()
  txtOutput.overwrite(model_header)
  txtOutput.appendLine().append(content)
```

But I get the following problem "Requested array size exceeds VM limit" that I can't manage since I am coding in Databricks so I cannot tweak it, so I need any way to process my data

Comment: You need to read the file line by line until you find the header. Save the header, rewind to start of file. Then, print the header to another file, and read each line from the source, print it to the new file. Skip the header in the source file. Once you reach the end of the source, close the new file, close the source, and delete the source. This assumes you have sufficient disk capacity to hold two copies of the file.